# Buildozer ouput error when trying to build android app (Kivy)

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

I'm getting this error whenever I try to build an android app written in Python 3 (Kivy). I'm working under Linux Mint 19. I've tried reinstalling buildozer, as well as Kivy and I don't know what else I could try, since I'm always getting the same error.

```
buildozer android debug
https://pastebin.com/26FPNjRM
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: Post the full log.

Comment: Ok, I posted the full log. Sorry about that.

Comment: Hmm, new to me. You could possibly try cleaning the sdk download (delete ~/.buildozer) and running again, but this will repeat the initial big download. It could also be that sdkmanager has changed and this is a bug, I don't know about that